# Yii2 - The directory is not writable by the Web process | frontend/web/assets

Tags: php, web, yii2, centos7

I have searched this issue on internet but none of them helped me.
Also this one doesn`t:

```
chgrp apache /path/to/mydir
chmod g+w /path/to/mydir
```

My server is centos 7. Can you help me?

Comment: apache servers usually run as user:group www-data:www-data

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try with following commands:

1. This will give you the name of apache user.
   **`ps -ef | grep apache | grep -v grep`**

   In most of the cases the user will be www-data.
2. Run these command after going into the /frontend/web folder: 
   **`sudo chgrp www-data ./assets`** 
   and 
    **`sudo chmod g+w ./assets/`**

Your problem will be solved.

Comment: @sam: I have installed nginx in amazon ec2, still i am getting "Exception (Invalid Configuration) 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'The directory is not writable by the Web process'"

Comment: @Maulikpatel have you tried executing above commands for nginx user:group ?

Comment: This doesn't work for me on centos7 is there any other solution?

Comment: on macosx it says **chgrp: www-data: illegal group name**

Comment: this doesn't wotk on Ubuntu even as su

Answer (score 16):

I have the problem too (in CentOS7). I tried to change the owner and group, but it didn't work. Finally, I closed the `selinux`, and it work.

```
setenforce 0
```

If you want to close it forever, you can change the `/etc/selinux/config` file:

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

Comment: worked for me. directory was 777 given. But error was same. After disable selinux start working

Comment: Awesome @lizs this answer should have been ACCEPTED one

Comment: first change config file but not worked, when set setenforce 0 worked for me,thanks @lizs

Answer (score 6):

i have same issue in ubuto instance i did like that and issue solve

```
sudo chmod 777 /home/nicjccom/public_html/asset
```

and also did this

```
sudo chgrp root /home/nicjccom/public_html/asset
```

Comment: Thank you @Adil, but issue was on CENTOS 7.  I've already solved it by Sam's answer.

Comment: @Adiii I have installed nginx in amazon ec2, still i am getting "Exception (Invalid Configuration) 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'The directory is not writable by the Web process'"

Comment: This worked for me with Docker and Ubuntu 21.04

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t 'YOUR_PATH_HERE'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command

I am giving permissions to html folder in www.My html folder contains multiple projects.

```
chgrp -R user html/
chmod -R g+w html/
chmod -R g+w html/
```

Comment: which commands are you executing? Execute with commands with sudo as prefix

Comment: I think you have to give permissions to assets folders

Answer (score 0):

If you're use php-fpm v7.4 and all your user/group are correct.
you can use

`systemctl edit php-fpm`

```
[Service]
ReadWritePaths = /usr/share/webapps/yii2-basic/web/assets
```

and add above config,then

`systemctl restart php-fpm`