# upload icon on localhost work but on server not work with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

when I upload it on localhost it work perfectly, but when upload it to server and I try to upload new file it return me HTTP ERROR 500, I don't know why ? 
And I also have my .htacess

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|chat|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Anyone please command with my issue ?

Comment: have you checked logs? Kindly paste logs here.

Comment: It can be permission problem, please show your logs.

Comment: ERROR - 2017-05-31 07:16:06 --> 404 Page Not Found: Assets/images

Comment: I believe you have shared recent logs. Also if this is the one then it might be the issue related to your directory structure or naming. Also check whether Apache has write permission to upload folder.

Comment: on more, I want to ask you about permission on server how to check it ?

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482597/yii2-the-directory-is-not-writable-by-the-web-process-frontend-web-assets/35167901#35167901).

Comment: I have check my code, And I think it not relate to folder assets/image , I stored it on another folder uploads. why it return me not found Assets/images .