# Why `the directory is not writable by the Web process` if the directory appears as writable?

Tags: apache, yii, yii2, humhub

I have issues installing [HubHub](https://humhub.org/). I keep getting this error

> Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
>   The directory is not writable by the Web process:
>   /var/www/html/humhub/assets

Although the folder is writable by `apache`:

```
$ ls -la /var/www/html/humhub/assets

total 0

drwxrwsrwx. 2 francesco apache 6 Jun 26 14:13 .

drwxrwsrwx. 7 francesco apache 197 Jun 26 14:13 ..
```

My setting:

- Server: Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.0 (Ootpa) on AWS
- HumHub: 1.3.14 (and Yii Framework/2.0.15)
- Web server: Apache/2.4.37 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux)

What I tried:

- I made sure the folder was writable by following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/58728) and [this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35167901/1707938)
- I even try to set the entire folder `humhub` as writable with `chmod -R 777 humhub`
- I made sure that all the PHP requirements were satisfied.

Is it possible that the web process is actually not run by `apache` with this result?

```
> ps -ef | grep httpd | grep -v grep
root     20227     1  0 05:30 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   20229 20227  0 05:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   20230 20227  0 05:30 ?        00:00:12 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   20231 20227  0 05:30 ?        00:00:12 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   20232 20227  0 05:30 ?        00:00:11 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   20449 20227  0 05:31 ?        00:00:13 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

Comment: are you by any chance using phpfpm ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam What's that? I don't know if I'm using it. How do I find it out?

Comment: have you tried to reassign folder owner to `wwwdata`?, i remember that apache is associate with wwwdata while installing. `sudo chown wwwdata:wwwdata /var/www/your_project -R`

Comment: Well, permissions are already 777 so the owner/group doesn't really matter here. I doubt it's using the deprecated safe_mode and its safe_mode_gid option too.

Comment: @Capsule i agree, but in this case all supposed to execute, like it should. I would probably try to restart server and php, after that update all dependencies.

Comment: @CptNemo do you have SELinux enabled on that server?

Comment: @Capsule Well, it was exactly that! As soon as I `setenforce Permissive` I was able to load get the installation started

Comment: @CptNemo then you have your culprit. Check that article: https://blog.lysender.com/2015/07/centos-7-selinux-php-apache-cannot-writeaccess-file-no-matter-what/